# Asynctask strange behaviour

Tags: android, android-asynctask, google-cloud-messaging

I met some strange warning with asynctask.I'm learning GCM so I try to use the asynctask.
this is the warning:

```
Type safety: The method execute(Object...) belongs to the raw type AsyncTask. References to generic type AsyncTask<Params,Progress,Result> should be parameterized
```

I want to understand the meaning of this warning.IS it about threads .why it not safe? and what is this raw?

this is my code:

```
private void registerInBackground() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



    new AsyncTask() {
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String msg = "";
            try {
                if (gcm == null) {
                    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                }
                regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
                msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid;

                // You should send the registration ID to your server over HTTP,
                // so it can use GCM/HTTP or CCS to send messages to your app.
                // The request to your server should be authenticated if your app
                // is using accounts.
                sendRegistrationIdToBackend();

                // For this demo: we don't need to send it because the device
                // will send upstream messages to a server that echo back the
                // message using the 'from' address in the message.

                // Persist the regID - no need to register again.
                storeRegistrationId(getApplicationContext(), regid);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                // If there is an error, don't just keep trying to register.
                // Require the user to click a button again, or perform
                // exponential back-off.
            }
            return msg;
        }   @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }.execute(null, null, null);



}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AsyncTask is a [generic Class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java) that can parameterized. The warning means that you should explicitly name the parameters.

The AsyncTask is defined as `AsyncTask<Params,Progress,Result>`, it needs 3 Parameters `Params`, `Progress` and `Result` that can be any Type/Class.

In your code above you return a String in `doInBackground()`. The return value of `doInBackground()` is the third parameter of the `AsyncTask` (`Result`).

To make the warning go away, implement your `AsyncTask` like this:

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            String message = "";

            //do something

            return message;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        }
    }.execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually `AsyncTask` is used/instantiated with parameters ... `AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>`. What the parameters signify are:

**Params:**

They are `Objects` that you pass into the `doInBackground()`. For example if I initialize the `Params` to be a `String`, I can now access the string parameter with in my `doInBackground(String... params)` from `params[0]`, `params[1]`, etc. This is one of the most important parameter that you specify because on calling the `AsyncTask` you can send in the parameter needed in the `doInBackground` thread. like new `AsyncTask().execute(string);`

**Progress:**

When using the `AsyncTask` one usually occupies the activity for loading content etc. You can use the progress parameter to give context to the user's that things are going the way they should. Suppose you are blocking the user interface telling your user that it's downloading content. With this progress you can specify how much of your content has been downloaded. If for example this parameter is an `integer` I could call the `publishProgress()` in the `doInBackground` thread to show progress on the content currently being downloaded.

**Result:**

Usually this is the only parameter that is allowed to interact with the user interface. Suppose you are done downloading your content. And would want to specify that the operation is complete displaying a success message. This is where you do it. For example, you would like to return a `String` saying that the download is now complete. In your `doInBackground` thread you `return string;` at the end. This value is thus passed into the `onPostExecute(String result)`. From there you could set `textView.setText(result)`.

Basically AsyncTask is based on the principal of `GENERICS` and `VARARGS` (java concepts)

GENERICS implying that the parameter in `AsyncTask` can be of any type and VARARGS specifying that you can send in multiple values inside these parameters.

In you case, since you are not doing anything pretty significant to change the UI you could call `AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>`. For better understanding on the workings of the `AsyncTask` you could see the following [example](https://github.com/rakeeb11/asyncsimple).

It's a long read but hope this clears up things :)

Answer (score 0):

Its to do with generics. The typing of the `AsyncTask` class is `AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>`. The message you're getting is because you're doing `new AsyncTask()`. What you should be doing is something like `new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>()` since you're not going to use those types anyway.

The API reference has more info on the subject.[enter link description here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)